# User Sessions with Vaadin Flow

Tags: vaadin10, vaadin-flow

I am currently a budding Java developer that wants to get into Vaadin development and currently trying to implement User Session login for my application. I have read about the content regarding the usage of VaadinServlets to do so : https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/advanced/tutorial-application-lifecycle.html.

After relentlessly digging through API documentations and sample codes, I still am not able to understand how to implement the User Sessions for a specific user that logs into my platform. From what I understand is that, I can initialize my user session by using what i have implemented below.

However my aims for the application are slightly different:

[Use Case]

1.User logs in with their specific credentials.

2.Gets Redirected to a SecuredPage (which will create a User Session storing the user's username and retrieves a token?)

3.After 2-3mins of inactivity, the User will get forced out of the SecuredPage and Session closes?

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "VaadinFlowServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(heartbeatInterval = 5, productionMode = false)
public class LoginServlet extends VaadinServlet implements SessionInitListener, SessionDestroyListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginServlet.class);

    // <Method> ::servletInitialized():: -> handles most of the servlet customization. (write my servlet customization under this function.
    //          ::getService()::         -> returns a VaadinServletService type?
    //          ::addSessionInitListener(this)::    -> An event listener that can be registered to a VaadinService to get an event -> when a new Vaadin service session is initialized for that service.
    //          ::addSessionDestroyListener(this):: -> A listener that gets notified when a Vaadin service session is no longer used.
    @Override
    protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
        super.servletInitialized();
        getService().addSessionInitListener(this);
        getService().addSessionDestroyListener(this);

    }

    // <Method>     ::sessionInit::      -> Starts Session?
    // <Parameter>  ::SessionInitEvent:: -> Event gets fired when a new Vaadin service session is initialized for a Vaadin service.
    @Override
    public void sessionInit(SessionInitEvent event) throws ServiceException{
        // Do Session start stuff here
        // Creates a Session?

        LOGGER.info("session init() "
                + " Session-ID: " + event.getSession().getSession().getId()
                + " CSRF: " + event.getSession().getCsrfToken());

    }

    // <Method>     ::sessionDestroy:: -> Stops Session?
    // <Parameter>  ::SessionDestroyEvent:: -> Event fired when a Vaadin service session is no longer in use.
    @Override
    public void sessionDestroy(SessionDestroyEvent event) {
        // Do session end stuff here
        LOGGER.info("session destory()");
    }

    }
```

1
So I was wondering if anybody can help me understand this matter better? Fully Appreciated

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

The mere existence of a custom-defined user-login object stored as an attribute in the key-value store of your `VaadinSession` represents the user having successfully authenticated. No need for all the session-listener code you wrote.

## Let Vaadin do the heavy-lifting

I suspect you are working too hard.

There is no need for your session listeners. Vaadin handles nearly all the Java Servlet details on our behalf.

No need for the [redirects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection). As a Vaadin developer, you are in full control of the content displayed in the browser tab/window, so you can switch between login form and main app content. Caveat: I am new to the `@Route` feature in Vaadin Flow, so there may be a [niftier way with that feature](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-lifecycle.html) to flip between login and main-content. And if you are using `@Route` for multiple views, each of those views should test for the authentication as described below.

### `VaadinSession`

At the entry point of your Vaadin app code, retrieve the current [`VaadinSession`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/12.0.3/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinSession.html) object. This `VaadinSession` is a wrapper around the [`javax.servlet.http.HttpSession`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) class defined by the [Java Servlet spec](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/). Vaadin automatically instantiates a session when the user’s browser first connects to your Vaadin web app (actually, Vaadin wraps the session instantiated by your [web container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container)). The session is automatically closed when the browser closes its tab/window, a time-out of inactivity occurs, or you programmatically close the session.

```
VaadinSession vaadinSession = VaadinSession.getCurrent() ;
```

### Session attributes (key-value store)

Interrogate that session object’s [key-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) store known as “attributes”. The key is of type `String` and the value is of type [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) (the superclass of all Java objects). After retrieving the `Object` object, you cast to the known class. You know the class, because it is your code that stored the attribute.

### Your user-login class

You would have defined a class to store your user-login related info. Perhaps you named it `UserLogin`.

Something like:

```
public class UserLogin {
    // Member values.
    String userName ;
    Instant whenAuthenticated ;

    // Constructor.
    public UserLogin( String userNameArg , Instant whenAuthenticatedArg ) {
        this.userName = userNameArg ;
        this.whenAuthenticated = whenAuthenticatedArg ;
    }
}
```

### Attempt to retrieve object of your user-login class from the session’s key-value store

Retrieve such an object of that type from the session attributes key-value store.

```
String attributeName = "my-user-login" ;
UserLogin userLogin = vaadinSession.getAttribute( attributeName ) ;
```

Rather than invent an attribute name, you could just use the class name. The [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) class lets you [ask for the name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getName()) of a class as text.

```
String attributeName = UserLogin.class.getName() ;
UserLogin userLogin = vaadinSession.getAttribute( attributeName ) ;
```

If you want to use the class name as the key in this way, the `VaadinSession` class provides a shortcut.

```
UserLogin userLogin = vaadinSession.getAttribute( UserLogin.class ) ;
```

Check to see if your `UserLogin` object is null. If you retrieved a `null`, then you know you have not yet stored an attribute (or willfully stored a null).

If not null, it means your user already has an active `UserLogin` object stored. How could they be logged-in already if the entry point of your app is executing? This can happen if the user hits the *Reload* button on their browser window. (Train your user not to do so on a [single-page web app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) such as Vaadin.)

### Outline of code to write

```
UserLogin userLogin = vaadinSession.getAttribute( UserLogin.class ) ;
if( Objects.isNull( userLogin ) ) {
    … display login form …
    … when authenticated, instantiate a `UserLogin` and store as attribute …
    if( authenticationSuccessful ) {  // Testing some did-user-authenticate variable you defined in your login-form.
        Instant whenAuthenticated = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC. 
        UserLogin userLogin = new UserLogin( userName , whenAuthenticated ) ;
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute( UserLogin.class , userLogin ) ;  // Using class name as the `String` key tracking this `userLogin` object.
        … switch content of the tab/window from authentication form to your main app content …
    } 
} else {  // Else not null. User already authenticated. User may have hit "Reload" button in browser. 
    … display app content … 
    … perhaps log this event … maybe user needs to be trained to not hit Reload on a Single-Page Web App …
}
```

---

By the way… the discussion above about sessions is scoped to each user’s own connection to your web app in a single web browser tab/window.

At some point you may look for a hook into the lifecycle of your entire web app, before the first user connects and/or after the last user disconnects, learn about the hook defined in the Java Servlet spec. This hook is the [`ServletContextListener`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) interface, where “context” means your web app as a whole. This is standard Java Servlet stuff, not at all specific to Vaadin, but Vaadin is actually a Servlet (perhaps the most sophisticated Servlet ever) so this context listener paradigm applies.

You write a class implementing that interface, by writing the before-first-user and the after-last-user methods. Identify your class to the web container by annotating `@WebListener` (or alternative means). Search Stack Overflow as this has been covered multiple times already.